# Is it just me or is "I can't tell them apart" odd?

Tags: phrases

As I understand it, "[tell](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell)" usually refers to talking or explaining something to someone. If you "can't tell", it means you don't have enough information to determine what to say.

However, this doesn't quite seem to fit with the phrase "I can't tell them apart". The meaning seems pretty clear at first glance, but on closer inspection it appears to me that the speaker is saying that they "can't [explain to] them apart", which doesn't make a lot of sense.

What is happening here?

Comment: This is not an idiom...

Comment: @medica I guess not exactly an *idiom*, but it seems like a bit of an odd phrase if the words at taken literally.

Comment: _Tell_ in its 'perceive' sense is in a number of idioms: _tell time, tell his ass from a hole in the ground, tell shit from Shinola_, plus many constructions with a 'discern' sense: _I can't tell who it is at this distance, I can tell what she's thinking_. These are all "Possible-Polarity" and require _can_ or some other Possible modal: **My brother-in-law told time yesterday*.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Certainly, *can't tell shit from Shinola* (I haven't heard that in quite a while) and other *tell* constructions are idioms, but is *tell them apart* an idiom? (Am truly curious) Is *tell apart* not used as *distinguish* enough to be self-explanatory?

Comment: @medica I don't know if the exact sequence of words "tell them apart" is an idiom but there are plenty of phrases such as "I can't tell the difference between X and Y" where tell means "perceive" rather than "inform".

Comment: Google for "define: tell".  The result says "tell, verb: [...] 2.
decide or determine correctly or with certainty."

Comment: Can you use _tell them apart_ without a modal? How does _I told them apart yesterday_ sound to you? If it sounds funny, you got a positive-polarity idiom here.

Comment: This is the problem with looking up a grammatical question in the dictionary. The dictionary won't tell you that something is an NPI, or Positive Polarity, or anything else syntactic about it. Dictionaries don't do grammar; they do word meanings, divorced and abstracted from usage. Not grammar.

Answer (score 6):

Definition 2.1 at [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tell?searchDictCode=all) is:

> Perceive (the difference between one person or thing and another): *I can’t tell the difference between margarine and butter*

This is the sense that's used in *tell them apart*.